# Symbols in PSPICE

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pspice

i have this circuit : [image]

And i must create it in PSPICE.. But i can't find the symbols which are in red squares. Can you tell me where are ? ( in which library, and the name )

Comment: These are *labels*. And a voltage source (probably AC) on the left. I really don't get what makes you "must create" given you don't know even the very basic of schematics.

Comment: I am student   :)

Comment: @Eugene Sh you don't have to be that rude. The question is this: how the elements in red rectangle can be represented in a Spice circuit. Using VAC, VDC, something else? I don't think it's a stupid question, especially for a student. If you can answer this then help him.

Comment: @Thanasis Pointing a basic problem with the prerequisites ordering is not "being rude". You can't read (or write) a book if you don't know the alphabet.

Comment: Search for "Vac" to be used for ac analyses or "Vsin" if you intend to perform a TRAN analysis (time domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi is your input voltage source. The sinusoidal symbol inside of it means it should be an AC voltage.

The other two elements in red squares are simply connection points. The top one (labeled Vdd) is a DC voltage supply (perhaps 5V DC). You should use a DC voltage source in the software to model this. Connect the positive to the point shown in the schematic, and the negative to ground (the same ground as connected to the source of the FET).

The element in the other red box is simply an output terminal. This is where you will take your measurements from. Your meter/probe will be connected between this point (labeled Vo) and ground.